Textbook question on evaluating complex square root
Let $f(z) = [(1-z)(z^2 + 1)]^{1/2}$. Let $f(0)=1$. If the z follows a contour from 0 to 2 which lies in the first quadrant of the complex plane, what is $f(2)$?
The book lists the correct answer as $-i \sqrt{5}$. I find the answer to be $i \sqrt{5}$. I have come to realize that if I factor out an $i$ from the $(1-z)$ term, I get the negative branch and this gives me the correct answer. However, I do not understand why this answer is correct nor why factoring out an i changes my branch despite searching high and low through the relevant books I have on hand. I fear I may be missing something fundamental.
My logic for my solution is that a contour through the first quadrant will not encircle any branch points. I should thus be safe to determine plus-minus of root using $f(0)= 1$ condition then directly plug in $f(2)$

Are you interested in the correct solution only, or in finding the mistake in your reasoning as well? If the latter, you should show the steps that you did.

There aren't really any steps that I took. I plugged in f(0) into given expression. Saw it was 1, and plugged in f(2) which gave me the wrong answer. However, the justification of my method was that a contour traveling through the first quadrant will not encircle any branch points, and thus will remain on the same branch. edit: added to question

You cannot plug in and get “an answer.” Where have you defined a branch of the square root?

@TedShifrin I’m plugging in because when I plug in f(0) into the expression I get 1. Thus, I can use the branch with no phase factor. Whereas, if I factor i out of first term, f(0) = -1, so I choose the branch with $e^{i \pi} $ factor

Let’s try this. Take a semicircle centered at $1$ and go (clockwise) from $0$ to $2$. What does $\sqrt{1-z}$ do as you follow the semicircle?

$\sqrt{,1 - z,},$ has a branch-cut along $\left[1,\infty\right)$. So, $\operatorname{f}\left(2\right)$ is undefined.

@FelixMarin No, in this case there are no branch cuts - the square root is understood as a complete analytic function.

"A contour through the first quadrant will not encircle any branch points" is not a valid argument - whichever path you take, you always make a fractional revolution around all branch points. The final value of $f$ is the result of applying these revolutions to the initial value.
One way to solve the problem is to write
$$f(z) = \sqrt{1-z} \cdot \sqrt{z^2+1} =: g(z) \cdot h(z)$$
and see how the value of each root changes along any path inside the first quadrant. We may assume that $g(z) = h(z) = 1$ at $z = 0$ (the other choice would work as well).

When $z$ goes from $0$ to $2$ along the path, the value $1-z$ does a $-\pi$ rotation about zero. The square root halves the angle, so $g(2) = -i$.



Since homotopic paths give the same final value, we may choose to go along the X axis when computing $h(2)$. Then $h(z)$ coincides with the real function $\sqrt{z^2+1}$, so $h(2) = \sqrt{5}$.


It follows that $f(2) = g(2) \cdot h(2) = -i \sqrt{5}$.

I have several points of confusion. First, this claim “We may assume $g(0)=h(0)=0$ (the other choice would work as well).” Why can we assume this. Second, it seems like only when z travels along z axis I can plug values in. I don’t understand why this is the case.

@EEH There are a couple ways to treat square roots and I'm not sure which of them you're assuming, so I'll go with one possible treatment. A function of the form $w(z) = \sqrt{u(z)}$ is completely defined only once we choose one of its two possible values at some starting point. Specifically, if $w_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfies $(w_0)^2 = u(z_0)$, we must choose between $w(z_0) = w_0$ and $w(z_0) = -w_0$. In this setting the formula $\sqrt{u(z) \cdot v(z)} = \sqrt{u(z)} \cdot \sqrt{v(z)}$ is true provided that it holds at any single point.

I defined $g(z) = \sqrt{1-z}$ and $h(z) = \sqrt{z^2+1}$ such that $g(0) = h(0) = 1$, since setting each of these values as $1$ or $-1$ was necessary to complete the definition. Now with this choice $g(z) \cdot h(z)$ coincides with $f(z) = \sqrt{(1-z)(z^2+1)}$ (defined by yourself - note that you also chose an initial value) at $z = 0$, so these functions are equal. Had I chosen $g(0) = h(0) = -1$ as a part of my definition, things would work similarly. But if I chose $g(0) = 1$ and $h(0) = -1$ (or the other way around), the identity $f(z) = g(z) \cdot h(z)$ would no longer be true.

I don't understand your second point: "only when $z$ travels along z [did you mean X?] axis I can plug values in".

Ok, I feel like I understand this question, but now I am curious given $f(z)=(g(z))^{1/2}$ where g(z) is analytic on a neighborhood U.  $z_0, z_1 \in U$ and the value of $f(z_0)$ is given. Is there a general procedure for finding $f(z_1)$? This question is motivated by realizing I don't know how to treat the case where $g(z)  = cos(z)$ and U is the metric ball centered at origin with radius greater than two pi (in other words U contains at least two zeros)

@EEH It is not a well posed question to find $f(z_1)$ given $f(z_0)$. Instead, given a path $\gamma : [0, 1] \to U$ and the value $f(\gamma(0))$, we can find $f(\gamma(1))$ (or $f(\gamma(t))$ for any $t \in [0, 1]$). Continuity of the square root makes it behave in a unique way along every path. But if only the endpoint is given, the value might depend on the path taken. However, there is a remarkable theorem: if $U$ is simply connected, then the value does not depend on the path.

Example: let $U = { z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 2 } \setminus { 0 }$ and $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ there. Let $f(1) = 1$. Then what is $f(-1)$? If you go along the path $\gamma(t) = \exp( \pi i t )$ (the upper semicircle), you will get $f(-1) = i$. But if you go along $\delta(t) = \exp(- \pi i t)$ (the lower semicircle), the final value is $-i$. What's more, if you go around the full circle, you will get $f(1) = -1$. :> Values of the square root are well defined over paths, not open sets (unless simply connected).

As for the general procedure, I can't say more than: imagine following the path in tiny steps, computing the square root along the way (paying particular attention to the angle, because the modulus is unique anyway). If you keep choosing the value that satisfies continuity, at the end of the path you will get the right result. Any other method is probably just a mathematical formalism to justify the answer obtained by following the path.

One of the biggest challenges here is that many things including $f$ were never actually defined in the original post, so I first define a choice of square root on a particular domain then compute the associated Argument implications.  I use the index to make this rigorous.
$D:= B\big(1,\sqrt{2}\big)-R$, where the ray $R=\Big\{1 + t\cdot \exp\left(\frac{-i}{2}\right)\Big\}$ for $t\geq 0$.
(In fact any ray 'pointing downward' from $1$ will work here.)
$g: D\longrightarrow \mathbb C-\big\{0\big\}$ given by
$g(z) = g_1(z)\cdot g_2(z)=\big(1-z\big)\cdot\big(z^2+1\big)$
$D$ is a simply connected Domain so there exists a particular branch $\text{Log}\circ g$ on $D$ which implies
$f:D\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by
$f\big(z\big) = \exp\Big(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\text{Log}\big(g(z)\big)\Big)= \exp\Big(\frac{1}{2}\cdot \text{ln}(\vert g(z)\vert) + \frac{1}{2}\cdot i\cdot\text{Arg}\big(g(z)\big)\Big)$
on its Domain we have $f(z)^2 = g(z)$, i.e. $f$ is a choice of square root of $g$ on $D$
thus $f(2) \in \big\{-i\sqrt{5}, i\sqrt{5}\big\}\implies f(2)= \sqrt{5}\cdot \exp\Big(\frac{1}{2}\cdot i \cdot\text{Arg}\big(g(2)\big)\Big)$
It remains to compute the Argument
$\gamma : [0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C$ given by $\gamma(t) = 1- \exp\big(-\pi i\cdot t\big)$
i.e. the simple semi-circular curve that starts at $0$ moves clockwise through $1+i$ and ends at $2$
$f(0)= 1\implies  \text{Arg}\big(g\big(\gamma(0)\big)\big)=\text{Arg}\big(g(0)\big) = k\cdot2\pi$  for some even $k$
remark: if we have a particular branch given by $\text{Arg}\big(g(z)\big)$ then $\text{Arg}\big(g(z)\big)+2\pi$ also gives a branch.  Knowing $f(0)=1$  allows us to determine that any multiple $k$ of $2\pi i$ is valid if $k$ is even and that odd $k$ corresponds to a branch for the "opposite" square root choice.
The index for the relevant non-closed curve is
$2\pi \cdot\Big( n\big(g_1\circ \gamma,0 \big)+ n\big(g_2\circ \gamma,0 \big)\Big)= 2\pi \cdot n\big(g\circ \gamma,0 \big) $
$= \text{Arg}\circ g\circ \gamma(1)-\text{Arg}\circ g\circ \gamma(0)=\text{Arg}\circ g\circ \gamma(1)-k\cdot 2\pi $
remark:  This is $I4$ and $I5$ in chapter 7 of Beardon's Complex Analysis.
(i.) $ n\big(g_1\circ \gamma,0 \big) = -\frac{1}{2}$
by direct calculation $\big($or extend $\gamma$ to $[0,2]$ making it a negatively oriented closed curve, apply the Argument Principle and work backward$\big)$
(ii.) $n\big(g_2\circ \gamma,0 \big) =0$
since $g_2\big(\gamma(0)\big)$ and $g_2\big(\gamma(1)\big)$ are both on the positive half line, so the index is integer valued and the curve never intersects the negative half line $\big[$check $\text{Re}\big(g_2(\gamma(t))\big)\geq 1-\text{Im}\big(\gamma(t)^2 \big)\geq 0\big]$ hence the index has modulus $\lt 1$, i.e. it is zero.  $\big($Alternatively consider $\sigma$, the curve from $\gamma(1)$ to $\gamma(0)$ whose image is a line segment; it is immediate that $n\big(g_2\circ \sigma,0 \big) =0$ and the Argument Principle tells us $0=n\big(g_2\circ \Gamma,0\big)= n\big(g_2\circ \gamma,0\big) + n\big(g_2\circ \sigma,0\big)$ for the cycle $\Gamma =(\gamma,\sigma)$.$\big)$
$\implies 2\pi \cdot\Big( -\frac{1}{2} + 0 \Big)+k\cdot 2\pi= \text{Arg}\circ g\circ \gamma(1) = \text{Arg}\Big(g\big(2\big)\Big)$
$\implies f(2)= \sqrt{5}\cdot \exp\Big(\frac{1}{2} \cdot i \cdot \big( -\pi + k\cdot 2\pi\big)\Big)= \sqrt{5}\cdot \exp\Big(\frac{-i\pi}{2}\Big)\exp\Big(k\cdot i\pi\Big)= -i\sqrt{5}$
since $\exp\Big(\frac{-i\pi}{2}\Big) = -i$ and $\exp\Big(k\cdot i\pi\big)=1$ because $k$ is even
